# Scrolling to the bottom inside a div triggers an alert (Pure JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I know there is already solutions on here but most of the solutions are written in jQuery and the JS version is based on the window but I need a method that works

for a div and for personal reasons I need to do this in pure JavaScript. So basically I need an alert to be triggered when a user scrolls all the way to the bottom inside a div call a and i'm not referring to the scrollbar of the window just to clear up confusion.

```js
document.querySelector('#a').addEventListener('scroll',scrollTrigger);

function scrollTrigger(){
  if(???){
    alert('End of scroll');
  }
}
```

```css
#a{
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
  <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
</div><!--</a>-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is "at the bottom" when
[`Element.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) + [`Element.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) is equal to the [`Element.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight).

```js
document.querySelector('#a').addEventListener('scroll',scrollTrigger);

function scrollTrigger(e) {
    const a = e.currentTarget;
  
    // use greater than or equal to be sure.
    if (Math.ceil(a.scrollTop) + a.clientHeight >= a.scrollHeight) {
        alert('End of scroll');
    }
}
```

```css
#a{
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
  <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
   <h1>a</h1>
</div><!--</a>-->
```

Comment: Thanks David for your response this code is very effective and it works amazingly on all the browsers on the pc and it also works on browsers on mobile android but for some reason this does not work on mobile safari like the Iphone, Ipad etc... any solutions how I can get this to work on those apple mobile devices?

Comment: Does this specific example not work for you in iOS Safari?
It does for me (on iOS 11.4.1).

If you `console.log` the values of `a.scrollTop`, `a.clientHeight`, `a.scrollHeight`, what are they when you reach the bottom?

Or are the markup and styles you're working with quite different from the example? If so, could you provide a more accurate version?

Comment: Here is a version on Codepen with some logging set up: https://codepen.io/davidding/pen/JaBdRy

Comment: Ok. `scrollTop`can give decimal values, if display scaling is used. We can `Math.round` `scrollTop` - or use `Math.ceil` to be sure.

I will update the answer (and the Codepen).

Comment: Sorry David I fell asleep wow these answers are getting closer thanks for responding I really appreciate that and it is now working on Iphone. I tested this as far back to Iphone 4 which is running ios 7 but on Ipad 4  on ios 8 strangely enough it does not work the reason why I tried it on those old devices and ios versions because that's the farthest i'm willing to support. Any other solutions to get this to work on the Ipad?

Comment: I assume you don't know how to solve the ipad issue but I really appreciate your advice I will ask another question based on solving the Ipad issue thank you very much David for your help.

Comment: Hey David I figure out the cause why it is not working on Ipad but I have not been able to understand why it does not work in certain desirable situations if your interested in more points then visit this new link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351145/display-block-elements-causes-the-script-to-not-work-in-certain-browsers

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.querySelector('#a').addEventListener('scroll', scrollTrigger);

function scrollTrigger() {

  var el = this;
  var sc = el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight - el.scrollTop;
  console.clear(); console.log(sc)

  if (sc === 0) {
    console.log('End of scroll');
  }
}
```

```css
#a {
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
  <h1>a---</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a---</h1>
</div>
```

If instead you want values from `0...1`

```
var sc =  el.scrollTop / (el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight );
```

`1` will indicate that the element fully scrolled:

```js
document.querySelector('#a').addEventListener('scroll', scrollTrigger);

function scrollTrigger() {

  var el = this;
  var sc = el.scrollTop / (el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight);
  console.clear(); console.log(sc)

  if (sc === 1) {
    console.log('End of scroll');
  }
}
```

```css
#a {
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
  <h1>a---</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a</h1>
  <h1>a---</h1>
</div>
```

`* 100` and you have percents ;)

Comment: Wow amazing Roko C. Buljan thanks for responding I am not ignoring you i'm just responding and testing code by one person at a time. This works on all the devices as well that I tested this on but this does not work on mobile safari on Ipad 4 which is running Ios 8 strangely enough this works on Iphone 4 which is running on Ios 7. Ios 8 is the farthest I will support any ideas to get this to work on Ipad?

Comment: @fsofb  (Not owning any one of those devices) Does the issue happens while trying to apply the above to BODY? Does the issue appears on an overflowed DIV (like in the example above) aswell?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
        // you're at the bottom of the page
         console.log("Bottom of page");
     }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I'm referring to a div call a not the window do you know a solution how I can trigger this based on the div scrollbar not the window scroll bar?